# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://apple.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: What is the minimum reputation for moderator nomination?

Comment: @Am1 There's a box on the right-hand side of the election page that explains each phase; you need 300

Comment: Are we unable to nominate other people?

Comment: @VxJasonxV No, self-nominations only. There's a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/) about the process that might be useful

Comment: That post would be a wonderful thing to link to on the election page(s). I don't believe I saw it anywhere. That, or the details could be made a little bit more permanent and linked to *that* instead per-network.

Comment: @VxJasonxV You can try asking a mod to add it (we added it on [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/election/1), along with a few other useful links)

Answer (score 1):

BTW, Winners were:

[image: Kyle Cronin]
[image: Philip Regan]
[image: Nathan G.]

Enjoy the diamonds!